# Lucas Numbers $(L_n)^2 = L_{2n} \pm 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, lucas-numbers

When I was looking at the Lucas Number Series I noticed the following:

- If $n$ is odd, then $(L(n))^2 = L(2n) - 2  $
- If $n$ is even, then $(L(n))^2 = L(2n) + 2  $

Can anyone provide a proof for why this is always true?

Comment: Hint: Binet's formula for Lucas number: $L_n = \varphi^n + (-\varphi)^{-n}$ where $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a standard fact that $L_n = \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n + \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n$ (and a [similar formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for Fibonacci numbers).  This is found by [solving the recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) defining the sequence.  So \begin{align*}
L_n^2 &= \left( \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n + \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n \right)^2  \\
    &= \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{2n} + 2 \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n + \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{2n}  \\
    &= L_{2n} + 2 \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n  \\
    &= L_{2n} + 2 \left( \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})(1-\sqrt{5})}{2 \cdot 2} \right)^n  \\
    &= L_{2n} + 2 \left( \frac{1-5}{4} \right)^n  \\
    &= L_{2n} + 2 (-1)^n  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Noticing that $n$ odd makes $2(-1)^n = -2$ and $n$ even makes $2(-1)^n = 2$, finishes the proof.